# Twilio outgoing events from client side js

Tags: twilio

is Twilio provided any outgoing events for another person call rejected or call answered

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I'm not sure what you're asking, can you be more specific please? It would be useful to know what you are trying to build and what feature you are asking about. Also, which product are you using here? I am guessing this is the [Twilio Voice SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am talking about Twilio voice SDK. for Twilio SDK they provided events only for connection.on("accept") and connection.on("disconnect").for outgoing call when the person is answered i didnt get any event from twilio and also outgoing call when the person rejects the calls